# Jersey @DefaultValue not working with Regex defined path

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

```
    @GET
    @Path("multiply/{first: ((\\+|-)?\\d+)?}{n:/?}{second:((\\+|-)?\\d+)?}")
    public String multiply(@PathParam("first") int first,
                           @DefaultValue("1") @PathParam("second") int second) throws Exception {
        return first * second;
    }
```

When request `HOST/multiply/3` result should be `3`, but  returned `0` since `second` for some reason is `0`, but should be `1`.

Why default value not set properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find somewhere in public email threads that `@DefaultValue` not working with `@PathParam` and the fact that this should work just an error/bug in jersey documentation.